# Implement existing experimental design in R

Tags: r, experimental-design

I want to use some existing designs from the literature and analyze them in R. However, so far all the packages and functions allow me to create a new design, which is great, but I don't know how to input a pre-existing design matrix.

As a particular example, I would like to use [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deudd.png) from this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6604/376f857c84a279118749f6f83cd869e2477f.pdf) and analyse it in R.

I tried creating my own lists as below to imitate the combination of levels in the attached table, but the FrF2 overrides my columns and create a new design. How can I prevent this and input my own table so that I can analyse and compare?

```
A = c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1)
B = c(-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1)
C = c(-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1)
D = c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)
E = c(-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1)
F = c(-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1)

my_factors = list(A,B,C,D,E,F)
FrF2(8,5,factors.name = my_factors, randomize = FALSE)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to validate your replicates value? use chisq.test(matrix)$p.value. Do you want to read your replicates values from text file? It will be helpful if you show first few lines of your data.

Comment: @kashiff007 thanks for the feedback, I tried adding more information to make it clearer. I want to use R to analyse my own design or others from the literature.